# Improve Clustered Key Index Seek with included columns, 75% cost

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm having issues with certain slow queries in SQL. We use .net entity framework and SQL. We have had a SQL consultant in a couple of years ago who added some non clustered key indexes on some of our worst offending tables. A maintenance plan is in place to re-organise indexes over night however we are still having a very high cost on Clustered Index Seek for tblDiaryAppointments. I'm no DBA but i feel i've learnt things along the way, from the pictures below the predicate is startDateTime which is ordered in the non clustered key but it seems it struggles to then find the associated diaryAppointmentID (PK). Should we be adding diaryAppointmentID to the included columns which is currently empty.

Predicate :

```
[CMS3SWE].[dbo].[tblDiaryAppointments].[startDateTime] as [Extent7].[startDateTime]<[@p__linq__1] AND (3)=[CMS3SWE].[dbo].[tblDiaryAppointments].[diaryAppointmentTypeID] as [Extent7].[diaryAppointmentTypeID]
```

Seek Predicates

```
[CMS3SWE].[dbo].[tblDiaryAppointments].diaryAppointmentID = Scalar Operator([CMS3SWE].[dbo].[tblDiaryAppointmentAttendees].[diaryAppointmentID] as [Extent6].[diaryAppointmentID])
```

Any help much appreciated

[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKz9R.png)

```
SELECT 
[Project34].[schemeID] AS [schemeID], 
 CAST( [Project34].[startDateTime] AS datetime2) AS [C1], 
[Project34].[clientID] AS [clientID], 
[Project34].[fullName] AS [fullName], 
[Project34].[C1] AS [C2], 
CASE WHEN ([Project34].[C2] IS NULL) THEN -1 ELSE [Project34].[C3] END AS [C3], 
[Project34].[C4] AS [C4], 
[Project34].[C5] AS [C5], 
CASE WHEN ([Project34].[C6] IS NULL) THEN -1 ELSE [Project34].[C7] END AS [C6], 
CASE WHEN ([Project34].[C8] IS NULL) THEN -1 ELSE [Project34].[C9] END AS [C7]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project32].[schemeID] AS [schemeID], 
    [Project32].[clientID] AS [clientID], 
    [Project32].[startDateTime] AS [startDateTime], 
    [Project32].[fullName] AS [fullName], 
    [Project32].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project32].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project32].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project32].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project32].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [Project32].[C6] AS [C6], 
    [Project32].[C7] AS [C7], 
    [Project32].[C8] AS [C8], 
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent22].[contractorID] AS [contractorID]
        FROM [dbo].[tblReferral] AS [Extent22]
        WHERE [Project32].[schemeID] = [Extent22].[schemeID]) AS [C9]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project31].[schemeID] AS [schemeID], 
        [Project31].[clientID] AS [clientID], 
        [Project31].[startDateTime] AS [startDateTime], 
        [Project31].[fullName] AS [fullName], 
        [Project31].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project31].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [Project31].[C3] AS [C3], 
        [Project31].[C4] AS [C4], 
        [Project31].[C5] AS [C5], 
        [Project31].[C6] AS [C6], 
        [Project31].[C7] AS [C7], 
        [Project31].[C8] AS [C8]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project29].[schemeID] AS [schemeID], 
            [Project29].[clientID] AS [clientID], 
            [Project29].[startDateTime] AS [startDateTime], 
            [Project29].[fullName] AS [fullName], 
            [Project29].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project29].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [Project29].[C3] AS [C3], 
            [Project29].[C4] AS [C4], 
            [Project29].[C5] AS [C5], 
            [Project29].[C6] AS [C6], 
            [Project29].[C7] AS [C7], 
            (SELECT TOP (1) 
                [Extent21].[contractorID] AS [contractorID]
                FROM [dbo].[tblReferral] AS [Extent21]
                WHERE [Project29].[schemeID] = [Extent21].[schemeID]) AS [C8]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project28].[schemeID] AS [schemeID], 
                [Project28].[clientID] AS [clientID], 
                [Project28].[startDateTime] AS [startDateTime], 
                [Project28].[fullName] AS [fullName], 
                [Project28].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project28].[C2] AS [C2], 
                [Project28].[C3] AS [C3], 
                [Project28].[C4] AS [C4], 
                [Project28].[C5] AS [C5], 
                [Project28].[C6] AS [C6], 
                [Project28].[C7] AS [C7]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project26].[schemeID] AS [schemeID], 
                    [Project26].[clientID] AS [clientID], 
                    [Project26].[startDateTime] AS [startDateTime], 
                    [Project26].[fullName] AS [fullName], 
                    [Project26].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    [Project26].[C2] AS [C2], 
                    [Project26].[C3] AS [C3], 
                    [Project26].[C4] AS [C4], 
                    [Project26].[C5] AS [C5], 
                    [Project26].[C6] AS [C6], 
                    (SELECT TOP (1) 
                        [Extent20].[teamID] AS [teamID]
```

Comment: you have an image of the execution plan and then you cover the important part with a pop up dialog.  Why did you do that?

Comment: better than an Image; use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Those subqueries, in subquery, in a subquery, in a.... are not going to help matters

Comment: There are so many red flags here I don't know where to begin. Aliases as the same name as the column. Column names that are meaningless and indicate a high likelihood of violating 1NF. Queries nested in queries nested in queries nested in queries. Columns in each level having the same name. Top with no order by. I am afraid the best way to fix this is by clicking [ctrl] + [n] and starting over, maybe all the way back at the table design.

Comment: That query isn't even complete.

Comment: submission claims its not a valid sql query plan yet thats what it generated

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BGaBEYmC8EB67caigyajv1qh8BdbLQujxwD0SDC6LRY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the query was generated by linQ

Comment: Can you please post the actual execution plan? And please don't post it as text on your google drive. Either follow the link above to paste the plan or post the document itself.

Comment: It looks like the actual SQL query will exceed SO character limits, and in any case it would be useless as you have no control over it. Please post the actual EF code that you are calling and, as others have said, the execution plan.

Comment: @SeanLange - this is EF generated code, so snide remarks about code quality should be directed to Microsoft and / or EF team. FYI, this is what it always looks like for non trivial queries.

Comment: I also requested the actual execution plan instead of the estimated one so we can try to help you find a solution.